# angular2 how to show property value in a div not stringified

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and still trying to figure out some things.
I have a property of the component which is this:

```
myProp: any;
```

I have HTML code which is this:

```
<div>
    {{myProp}}
</div>
```

my problem is the value is shown stringify. which I don't want that because I use elements which I process and add in typescript code behind to style some text different than others and so, what I see now is the div with a long string of myProp value, but not like HTML elements.

I searched on the web and saw that this way of property value is being always stringified.
so I want to ask what is the way to do this  - use the property value to include HTML real elements.

Comment: what `myProp` is supposed to be ? an HTML tag ?

Comment: Please provide a little more detail. What's `myProp` supposed to look like? How do you pass it into the component?

Comment: It sounds like you have HTML either directly in `myProp` or as a field of `myProp`. See the suggested duplicate on how to render that. If I am wrong about my interpretation of your question please update it with what is contained in `myProp` and what you are expecting on the screen.

Comment: @Igor thanks:) you are right this is exactly it!

Comment: {{myProp | json}} if it is json

Comment: update your question anyway otherwise it's not very usefull for others